# How do I get these HTML tags to render from javascript

Tags: javascript

Noob question alert! So, I've got this script, which loops through an array and adds a `<br>` tag to the end of each array item. But i dont know the proper way of displaying this output on my page. Currently, when it loads the `<br>` tags show up on screen, whereas I want them to render as line-breaks. It is outputting into a `<textarea>` if that makes a difference. Thanks a bunch.

```
var outputLinkText = document.getElementById('outputLinkText');
var outputStageOne = "";

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
    outputStageOne += (arrayOne[i] + "<br>");
}   

if ( 'textContent' in timePlace ) {
    outputLinkText.textContent = outputStageOne;
}
else {
    outputLinkText.innerText = outputStageOne;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<textarea>` tags don't support `<br>` tags (or any other HTML tags) within their contents.  They *only* hold plain text.

You need to add `"\n"` as the separator instead.

(Strictly, it should be `"\r\n"` but a `"\n"` on its own is usually sufficient)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the textarea is a difference, try this :

`"\r\n"` instead of `"<br>"`